# dataframe is not getting converted into CSV and parquet

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I made a local dataframe and I am trying to covert the dataframe into CSV & Parquet. its throwing error, saying that -

for df to csv

```
        Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [18], in <cell line: 2>()
          1 #converting the datafram into csv
    ----> 2 df.write.csv('test.csv',header=True)
          3 spark.read.csv('test.csv',header=True).show()
    
    File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:955, in DataFrameWriter.csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue, lineSep)
        947 self.mode(mode)
        948 self._set_opts(compression=compression, sep=sep, quote=quote, escape=escape, header=header,
        949                nullValue=nullValue, escapeQuotes=escapeQuotes, quoteAll=quoteAll,
        950                dateFormat=dateFormat, timestampFormat=timestampFormat,
       (...)
        953                charToEscapeQuoteEscaping=charToEscapeQuoteEscaping,
        954                encoding=encoding, emptyValue=emptyValue, lineSep=lineSep)
    --> 955 self._jwrite.csv(path)
    
    File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
       1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
       1316     self.command_header +\
       1317     args_command +\
       1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
       1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    -> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
       1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
       1325     temp_arg._detach()
    
    File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
        109 def deco(*a, **kw):
        110     try:
    --> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
        112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
        113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    
    File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
        324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
        325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
    --> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
        327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
        328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
        329 else:
        330     raise Py4JError(
        331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
        332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o163.csv.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:496)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:839)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$20(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:605)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
        ... 42 more

for df to parquet 

    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o149.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:781)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$20(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    ... 42 more
```

My env path are correct. I am attaching the code of the dataframe creation and conversion below: -

```
import sys
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "C:/Mine/Spark/hadoop-2.6.0"
sys.path.append("C:/Mine/Spark/hadoop-2.6.0/bin")

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000,1,1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000,2,1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='string1', d=date(2000,3,1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0)),
])
df

#Dataframe schema 
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

I am getting correct output for this,

```
+---+---+-------+----------+-------------------+
|  a|  b|      c|         d|                  e|
+---+---+-------+----------+-------------------+
|  1|2.0|string1|2000-01-01|2000-01-01 12:00:00|
|  2|3.0|string2|2000-02-01|2000-01-02 12:00:00|
|  4|5.0|string1|2000-03-01|2000-01-03 12:00:00|
+---+---+-------+----------+-------------------+

root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: double (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d: date (nullable = true)
 |-- e: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

When I am trying to convert the dataframe into CSV or Parquet i am getting above error, the code I am using for the conversion are: -

for df to csv: -

```
#converting the datafram into csv
df.write.csv('test.csv',header=True)
```

for df to parquet

```
#converting to parquet 
df.write.parquet('test.parquet')
```

Comment: It would be useful to have the stack trace as well.

Comment: Add the full stack trace , the error is too vague to understand the actual cause

Comment: What Java version do you have? What Spark version are you running?

Comment: spark 3.2.1 and java sdk 1.11.563

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, i downloaded following files. And adding those in the jar folder of the Spark. After that restarting the kernel of the notebook.

[image]